# Getting member variables through reflection in Kotlin

Tags: reflection, kotlin

If I have a class in Kotlin:

```
class Foo{

var x= null
var y=null

}
```

I want to check which of these members have been set at runtime through reflection. I can iterate over them and check for null in Java.

```
Foo foo= new Foo();

//this gives me the value of foo.x
Foo.class.getDeclaredField("x").get(foo);
```

How can I do the same in Kotlin/Native? I know I can achieve this in Android by

```
Foo::class.java.getDeclaredField("x").get(foo)
```

But this doesn't work in native environment.

Comment: I don't understand why you accept the answer if it is not answering your question, :) Approved answer will not work for Kotlin native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going by the documentation, so the below may be a bit wrong, but you could try this:

```
val prop : KCallable = Foo::class.members.firstOrNull { it.name == "x" }
if (prop != null) {
   val xValue : Int? = prop.call(object)
    //you have to declare the type of the xValue
}
```

Comment: `members` only available on `JVM`: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/members.html